# How can preserve my manual edit of an expression when exporting to LaTeX?

Tags: front-end, export, latex

**Context**

I would like to use the *Mathematica* front end to pre-process 
expressions before exporting them to LateX, for the sake of readability.

**Example**

Say I have this expression

```
   (16*((-3 + r^2)*BesselI[0, r^2/8]^2 - ((-48 + 16*r^2 + r^4)*BesselI[0, r^2/8]*
   BesselI[1, r^2/8])/r^2 + 
   15*BesselI[1, r^2/8]^2)*Cos[2*\[Theta]])/(3*Sqrt[3]*E^(r^2/4))
```

which looks like this in *Mathematica*

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Once I edit it by hand within *Mathematica*, it might look like this:
(notice that its more publishable in that form)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(This is a great feature of the Front-End by the way!).

If I then select the expression and choose the export to latex menu, *Mathematica* exports the original (unedited) equation.

**Question**

How do I tell *Mathematica* to mind its own business and export to LaTeX the result of my edit, not its re-processing of it?

**EDIT**

Following the suggestion of @Nasser, I tried

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So it does not really preserve the original expression?

Comment: Try applying HoldForm[expr] when exporting. You might have to use HoldForm in more than one subpart of the expression if you want complete control. Hard to test it since your final expression is not posted in M code.

Comment: The expression you give as an example in markdown is not equivalent to the expression you show in the imbedded images.

Comment: @m_goldberg oops sorry.

Comment: @Nasser thanks. It does partially do the job, see my edit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the notebook interface, you can use HoldForm[] like this

```
expr2 = HoldForm[16 E^(-(r^2/4)) cos (2 \[Theta]) /(3 Sqrt[3])];
expr3 = HoldForm[((r^2 - 3) BesselI[0,r^2/8]^2 + 15 BesselI[1,r^2/8]^2 - 
        ((r^4 + 16 r^2 - 48) BesselI[1,r^2/8] BesselI[0,r^2/8])/r^2)];
TraditionalForm[expr2 expr3]
```

which gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which is what you wanted. Now, for Latex export

```
TeXForm[expr2 expr3]
```

which gives the tex expression. I copied this to my texlive box and run latex on it:

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}%
\begin{document}
$\left(\left(r^2-3\right) I_0\left(\frac{r^2}{8}\right){}^2+15 I_1
\left(\frac{r^2}{8}\right){}^2-\frac{\left(r^4+16
   r^2-48\right) I_1\left(\frac{r^2}{8}\right) I_0\left(\frac{r^2}{8}\right)}
{r^2}\right) \frac{16 e^{-\frac{r^2}{4}}
   \cos  (2 \theta )}{3 \sqrt{3}}$
\end{document}
```

and here is the pdf file result

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks again: inspired by your answer, it seems `Map[HoldForm, exp]//TeXForm`  does more or less the trick.